# Retornar a linha de uma tabela quando o valor do count(campo) for 0 no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query, null

Preciso que mesmo quando a busca não gere resultados, seja exibido o valor 0, tentei com a seguinte busca SQL, mas sem êxito:

```
    SELECT c.categoria as categoria,
           CASE WHEN COUNT(c.categoria) IS NOT NULL THEN count(c.categoria) ELSE 0 END AS quantidade
    FROM anuncio a
        RIGHT JOIN categoria c ON a.categoria = c.categoria WHERE autorizado = '1'
    GROUP BY c.categoria;
```

Comment: e você quer contar o que afinal ? os anuncios ou as categorias ?

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/546600-union-com-com-o-mesmos-dados-e-campo-diferentes/ veja se ajuda

Comment: Quero a quantidade anúncios por categoria.

Answer (score -1):

```
select codigo,count(id) as QUANTIDADE from(
select id,nome from (
select id from categoria
where ...
group by ID) as a
left join tabela on a.id=id
group by id,nome) as b
left join tabela on b.id=id 
group by código, id
```

Penso que isto o possa ajudar

Answer (score -1):

use o coalesce como um subselect:

```
select coalesce(
 (SELECT c.categoria as categoria,
        COUNT(c.categoria)AS quantidade
    FROM anuncio a
        RIGHT JOIN categoria c ON a.categoria = c.categoria WHERE autorizado = '1'
    GROUP BY c.categoria
), 0 )
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode estruturar a sua query de uma forma diferente, olha este exemplo do próprio [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9487991/7259765):

```
SELECT
       IFNULL(SUM(TOTAL), 0) AS total,
       IFNULL(SUM(5STAR), 0) AS FiveStar, 
       STORE,
       DATE
FROM `table`
WHERE DATE >= '2012-02-24'
GROUP BY TOTAL
```

Desta forma buscará o total e resultará 0 caso não encontre resultados.